# REST HTTP DELETE without named arguments

Tags: lwp, perl

I want to do:

```
 curl -X DELETE -d '{"name":"flowx"}' 'http://somewhere/wm/staticflowentrypusher/json'
```

In perl:

```
 my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
 my $url = 'http://somewhere/wm/staticflowentrypusher/json';
 $browser->delete($url, '{"name":"flowx"}');
```

But I get:

```
 Illegal field name '{"name":"flowx"}' at /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/HTTP/Request/Common.pm line 115
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments in LWP::UserAgent::delete() are used to create headers not content. Use HTTP:Request for that:

```
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'http://somewhere/wm/staticflowentrypusher/json';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(DELETE => $url);

$req->content('{"name":"flowx"}');
my $response = $browser->request($req);

say $response->content;
```